# Comparing meta-analyses with partially overlapping controls

Tags: meta-analysis, network-meta-analysis

I would like to compare to meta-analyses that have semi-overlapping controls.  In this situation, a single meta-analysis cannot be performed.  There are known methods for comparing metas of independent samples (wald) and shared controls (multiple treatments meta), but what is the best way to handle a situation with semi-overlapping controls (80% overlap) and independent cases between two metas?

Comment: I do not understand exactly if you mean overlapping meta-analyses or overlapping studies. If you can disentagle control and experimental groups from individual studies, then you can use either multivariate meta-analysis or network meta-analysis methods (eg mvmeta or netmeta R packages). If your study unit is meta-analysis, then it is much trickier to disentangle...

Comment: Can you give us an example of one of the studies with overlapping controls? What were the arms and how did the controls overlap?